# How do I mock the paramiko.SSHClient so that an error is raised on the connect call

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest.mock, pytest-mock

I am trying to write a unit test and raise an error from the `connect` call in the `paramiko.SSHClient`. Here is the code I want to test:

```
with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host_name, username=user_name, pkey=pk, port=port)
```

and this is what I have in the test:

```
def raiser():
    raise ValueError("test")
ssh_client_mock = mocker.patch('paramiko.SSHClient')
ssh_client_mock.connect.side_effect = raiser
```

When debugging, I can see that `with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:` give me an `ssh` instance that is a `MagicMock` - but the connect call does not raise ....

Answer (score 0):

ok I got this to work using:

```
def raiser(*args, **kwargs):
   raise ValueError("test")
ssh_client_mock = mocker.patch.object(paramiko.SSHClient, 'connect')
ssh_client_mock.side_effect = raiser
```